# css - letter-spacing under webkit - any workaround?

Tags: css, webkit, letter-spacing

i'm struggling with the fact that webkit browsers like safari won't support letter-spacing smaller than 1 pixel. is there any solution yet?
i was thinking about converting my font and adding letterspacing directly to that new font:
would this work and any ideas if there's a converter which supports that?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could always use `em`'s.

`letter-spacing: 0.5em;`

Comment: doesn't work - webkit will round values <1 .. for example 0.06em will have same result as 0em - 0.07em has same result as 0.1em - very annoying :/

Answer (score 0):

Sure they do. Try `0`, `-1px`, etc.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ovepan/edit#html,live

Output:

[image]

HTML:

```html
<p id="one">Letter spacing 1px</p>
<p id="zero">Letter spacing 0px</p>
<p id="negative-one">Letter spacing -1px</p>
```

CSS:

```css
#one {letter-spacing: 1px }
#zero {letter-spacing: 0px }
#negative-one {letter-spacing: -1px }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested the following on Safari and Chrome (Win 7):

```
<style>
.foo { letter-spacing: 0.7px; }
</style>
Hello world! This is sample text.
<div class=foo>Hello world! This is sample text.</div>
```

Initially the difference is barely noticeable, but if you zoom by Ctrl + you will see that the second text gets visibly wider, due to slighly larger letter spacing.

The quality of implementation might be subject to debate, but the support is there.

On the other hand, if you don’t like the natural appearance of a font, with spacing as caused designer’s decisions, use a different font. Mechanically increasing all letter spacing in text expresses distrust in font design and is a coarse tool. Letter spacing might be needed in special occasions for short texts, though—but less than a pixel is hardly useful then.